# datagridview update while typing

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, datagridview, cell

I'm making an accounting application, and I have a small problem. I need my datagridview to make the necessary cell computations while I'm writing in a cell not after I press a key or make any other type of validation... because the user may forget to do that.

So I have this, and my question is what event should I use to validate dgw cell while typing in it? Or there's another way to do this?

```
Private Sub NRCD_produseDataGridView_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e 
   As System.Windows.Forms.Da-taGridViewCellEventArgs) 
   Handles NRCD_produseDataGridView.???????

   // doesn't matter what is here 

End Sub
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

As you've observed, the [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event is not the right one for this situation. Why? Because the value of the edit control is yet to be pushed back to the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView(v=vs.110).aspx). The event you're looking for is [EditingControlShowing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing(v=vs.110).aspx). This will give you the ability to add handles to the actual edit control ([TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx), [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx), etc.) displayed in the [DataGridViewCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell(v=vs.110).aspx) when editing. Note that when a cell is not in edit mode, the cell is just an "image" of the edit control painted by the grid, it's not an actual control.

When asking question related to a DataGridView it's important to shared the following:

- Is the grid bounded to a data source?
- If yes, what is the type of the underlaying data source?
- Do you run the grid in [VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Now, since you haven't shared any of this, the following sample form assumes that the grid is:

- Bound to a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).
- Run in normal mode.

[image]

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.ClientSize = New Size(500, 300)
        Me.table = New DataTable()
        Me.table.Columns.Add("Text", GetType(String))
        Me.table.Columns.Add("Length", GetType(Integer))
        Me.table.Rows.Add("apple", 5)
        Me.table.Rows.Add("banana", 6)
        Me.table.Rows.Add("orange", 6)
        Me.textColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.DataPropertyName = "Text", .HeaderText = "Text", .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill}
        Me.lengthColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.DataPropertyName = "Length", .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Length (Computed)", .Width = 200, .MinimumWidth = 200}
        Me.grid = New DataGridView() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .AutoGenerateColumns = False, .DataSource = Me.table}
        Me.grid.Columns.AddRange({Me.textColumn, Me.lengthColumn})
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.grid)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleEcShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles grid.EditingControlShowing
        If (Me.grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = Me.textColumn.Index) Then
            Dim ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = DirectCast(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
            Me.UnhookEc(ec) 'Important: Remove handles to avoid recursion.
            Me.HookEc(ec)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleEcTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = DirectCast(sender, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        Dim cell As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = DirectCast(Me.grid.CurrentCell, DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
        Me.grid.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(Me.lengthColumn.Index).Value = ec.Text.Length
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleEcDisposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.UnhookEc(TryCast(sender, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)) 'Important: This will ensure removal of the hooked handles.
    End Sub

    Private Sub HookEc(ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        If (Not ec Is Nothing) Then
            AddHandler ec.TextChanged, AddressOf Me.HandleEcTextChanged
            AddHandler ec.Disposed, AddressOf Me.HandleEcDisposed
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub UnhookEc(ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        If (Not ec Is Nothing) Then
            RemoveHandler ec.TextChanged, AddressOf Me.HandleEcTextChanged
            RemoveHandler ec.Disposed, AddressOf Me.HandleEcDisposed
        End If
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents table As DataTable
    Private WithEvents grid As DataGridView
    Private WithEvents textColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Private WithEvents lengthColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

End Class
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry for delay. I tried EditingControlShowing but it didn't helped me. It acted like key press event, that's why I asked. The data is bound there is a access database, but I used it only to store my values (because I cound't succed to make the relations between tables and to work well). Anyway I'm not very experienced with programming and you said somethig about virtual / normal mode. Can you tell me which is the difference? Is when I press debug button vs when using the application in another computer?? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code and have added a TextBox.

If modified, for example the first cell, then I click on the TextBox and click again on the modified cell, to try writing again in the same cell, a rare effect and does not properly written in the same cell.
You need to change row and return to the previous cell to write back in that cell.

I am interested in the code work this way, but that does not make this weird effect.

If I remove the following line of code in the event HandleEcTextChanged (...)

Me.grid.Rows (cell.RowIndex) .Cells (Me.lengthColumn.Index) .Value = ec.Text.Length

the problem does not happen, but I need to update the Length column programmatically.

In addition, if the datagridview is connected to a database, you get an error "The index of the datatable it is damaged."

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Modify the first cell of datagridview "apple".
2. Click the TexBox "0000000".
3. Click on the cell modified above.
4. Enter any value in the current cell.
5. In the previous point the problem occurs. Do not write properly in the cell.

Help please.

Thanks.

```
Public Class TextBoxDirectCast

    Private WithEvents table As DataTable
    Private WithEvents grid As DataGridView
    Private WithEvents textColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Private WithEvents lengthColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Private WithEvents texboxtext As TextBox

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.ClientSize = New Size(400, 300)
        Me.table = New DataTable()
        Me.table.Columns.Add("Text", GetType(String))
        Me.table.Columns.Add("Length", GetType(Integer))
        Me.table.Rows.Add("apple", 5)
        Me.table.Rows.Add("banana", 6)
        Me.table.Rows.Add("orange", 6)
        Me.textColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.DataPropertyName = "Text", .HeaderText = "Text", .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill}
        Me.lengthColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.DataPropertyName = "Length", .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Length (Computed)", .Width = 200, .MinimumWidth = 200}
        Me.grid = New DataGridView() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Top, .AutoGenerateColumns = False, .DataSource = Me.table, .TabIndex = 0}
        Me.grid.Columns.AddRange({Me.textColumn, Me.lengthColumn})
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.grid)
        Me.texboxtext = New TextBox With {.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left, .Text = "0000000", .Location = New Point(10, Me.ClientSize.Height - 30), .TabIndex = 1}
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.texboxtext)
        Me.texboxtext.BringToFront()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleEcShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles grid.EditingControlShowing
        If (Me.grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = Me.textColumn.Index) Then
            Dim ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = DirectCast(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
            Me.UnhookEc(ec) 'Important: Remove handles to avoid recursion.
            Me.HookEc(ec)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleEcTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = DirectCast(sender, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        Dim cell As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = DirectCast(Me.grid.CurrentCell, DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
        Me.grid.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(Me.lengthColumn.Index).Value = ec.Text.Length
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleEcDisposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.UnhookEc(TryCast(sender, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)) 'Important: This will ensure removal of the hooked handles.
    End Sub

    Private Sub HookEc(ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        If (Not ec Is Nothing) Then
            AddHandler ec.TextChanged, AddressOf Me.HandleEcTextChanged
            AddHandler ec.Disposed, AddressOf Me.HandleEcDisposed
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub UnhookEc(ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        If (Not ec Is Nothing) Then
            RemoveHandler ec.TextChanged, AddressOf Me.HandleEcTextChanged
            RemoveHandler ec.Disposed, AddressOf Me.HandleEcDisposed
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Help with this isuue please, tanks